# Unable to identify syntax issue with using MAX and OVER PARTITION BY

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to answer a SQL Leetcode question on Medium Difficulty. The question is asking me to find the people that have the highest salary per department.

I tried using GROUP BY but wasn't able to figure out that approach so I tried to use the PARTITION BY in order to find the max salary for each department. Afterwards, I would add a final WHERE statement where I could filter down to people with a salary that equals the max salary.

This is the query I have so far:

```
SELECT 
    Department.Name AS Department, 
    Employee.Name AS Employee, 
    Employee.Salary,
    MAX(Employee.Salary) OVER (PARTITION BY Department.Name) AS MaxSalary
FROM Employee
LEFT JOIN Department ON Department.id = Employee.DepartmentId
;
```

There's two tables.

```
EMPLOYEE TABLE:

+----+-------+--------+--------------+
| Id | Name  | Salary | DepartmentId |
+----+-------+--------+--------------+
| 1  | Joe   | 70000  | 1            |
| 2  | Jim   | 90000  | 1            |
| 3  | Henry | 80000  | 2            |
| 4  | Sam   | 60000  | 2            |
| 5  | Max   | 90000  | 1            |
+----+-------+--------+--------------+

DEPARTMENT TABLE:

+----+----------+
| Id | Name     |
+----+----------+
| 1  | IT       |
| 2  | Sales    |
+----+----------+
```

and the correct output should look like this.

```
CORRECT EXPECTED OUTPUT:

+------------+----------+--------+
| Department | Employee | Salary |
+------------+----------+--------+
| IT         | Max      | 90000  |
| IT         | Jim      | 90000  |
| Sales      | Henry    | 80000  |
+------------+----------+--------+
```

Running my current query leads to a runtime error with this message:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(PARTITION BY Department.Name) AS MaxSalary
FROM Employee
LEFT JOIN Department O' at line 7
```

I've looked over the syntax multiple times so I assume it's a incorrect understanding of how PARTITION BY works. I was expecting that I would see the max salary for each department listed on the right for each individual. Something like this:

```
+----+-------+--------+--------------+-----------+
| Id | Name  | Salary | DepartmentId | MaxSalary |
+----+-------+--------+--------------+-----------+
| 1  | Joe   | 70000  | 1            | 90000     |
| 2  | Jim   | 90000  | 1            | 90000     |
| 3  | Henry | 80000  | 2            | 80000     |
| 4  | Sam   | 60000  | 2            | 80000     |
| 5  | Max   | 90000  | 1            | 90000     |
+----+-------+--------+--------------+ -----------+
```

After achieving that, I was going to add this line:

```
WHERE Employee.Salary = MaxSalary;
```

What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: What version of MySQL are you running?

Comment: At the time of this posting I think Leetcode is on 5.7.22

Comment: You need to be on 8 or over to use window functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can consider using one of the following:

```
SELECT D.Name AS Department, E.Name AS Employee, E.Salary
FROM Employee AS E LEFT JOIN Department AS D ON E.DepartmentId = D.id
WHERE (E.Salary = (SELECT MAX(X.Salary) FROM Employee AS X WHERE (X.DepartmentId = E.DepartmentId)));

SELECT D.Name AS Department, E.Name AS Employee, E.Salary
FROM Employee AS E LEFT JOIN Department AS D ON E.DepartmentId = D.id
INNER JOIN (SELECT DepartmentId, MAX(Salary) AS MaxSalary FROM Employee GROUP BY DepartmentId) AS X ON E.DepartmentId = X.DepartmentId AND E.Salary = X.MaxSalary;
```

Comment: For the first variation, can you explain this section of the last line?: 
"(SELECT MAX(X.Salary) FROM Employee AS X WHERE (X.DepartmentId = E.DepartmentId))" 

From a high level, I understand that you're able to get the max salary for the department that the person belongs in but I'm confused on the exact workings. Why do you need to have an Employee table as X and then another Employee table as E?

Comment: You are correct. The Employee table with the alias "E" is used to display the data you need. The WHERE clause involving the Employee table with the alias "X" is used to obtain the maximum Salary for the specific department where "E" belongs to and then filter the records from "E" who have this value in the Salary field.